# How do I relay First Name to the right of Hello after a user enters it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was given a large assignment for class and part of it is figuring out how to have a message appear after the person enters their first and last names into their fields that welcomes them. I've asked all my classmates about it and some have solved it but they are unwilling to share the code or explain to me how to do it.

here is what I have tried

```
function greeting() {   
    var firstName, lastName;
    firstName = prompt("Enter your First Name");
    lastName = prompt("Enter your Last Name");
    var greetingDiv = document.getElementById('greeting');
    greetingDiv.innerHTML = greetingDiv.textContent + ", " + firstName + " " + lastName;
    return greetingDiv.textContent = greetingDiv.textContent + ", " + " " + (firstName + " " + lastName);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: This is JavaScript, not Java. They're not the same at all.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with what you have so far?

Comment: Do you have any html to go with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to populate an element with the return from two prompts i think this will fit your needs.

```
function greeting() {   
    var firstName, lastName;

    firstName = prompt("Enter your First Name"); 
    lastName = prompt("Enter your Last Name");

    var greetingDiv = document.getElementById('greeting'); 
    greetingDiv.innerHTML = firstName + " " + lastName;
}

greeting();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!